# Remove from a list from starting index at once

Tags: c#, list

I would like to remove elements from a list at once. Not in a loop.
Currently I am passing a from index number as a starting number and then removing it in a loop which is causing a lot of problems. Is there a way to remove all at once?

Basically remove from index 3 till the end.

```
public List<string> steps = new List<string> (); //Total count 10
public int fromIndex; //index is 3

void Start(){

        int tempTrackNumber =  fromIndex;
        
        for(int i = tempTrackNumber; i < steps.Count; tempTrackNumber++) {
            steps.Remove(steps[i]);
        }

}
```

Comment: By "at once" do you mean concurrently (i.e., remove items from `fromIndex` till the end of list at the same time without recursion)? If so, have you looked into [RemoveRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removerange?view=net-7.0)? Otherwise, if you're interested in a multi-threaded approach, you would have to still lock the list to prevent concurrent modification of the list, which will still result in one-by-one removal of items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the elements in-place (i.e. without creating a brand new list and allocating extra memory for the same elements again as the accepted answer), you can use `RemoveRange` like this:

```cs
public List<string> steps = new List<string> (); //Total count 10
public int fromIndex; //index is 3

void Start()
{
        steps.RemoveRange(fromIndex, steps.Count - fromIndex);
}
```

If you need this in more places or want it to be slightly more intuitive to the reader, you can create a simple extension method to extract the behavior:

```cs
    public static void RemoveRangeFrom<T>(this List<T> list, int fromIndex)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(list);
        if (fromIndex < 0 || fromIndex >= list.Count)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(fromIndex), "Value needs to be a valid index into the list.");
        }

        list.RemoveRange(fromIndex, list.Count - fromIndex);
    }
```

And then call it like this:

```cs
steps.RemoveRangeFrom(fromIndex);
```

Comment: According to the code provided in the question, it is *in place solution* that OP looked for, and `RemoveRange` is a better choice than Linq in this case (less unwanted overhead); +1

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to remove elements from index `X` to the end of the list then the goal is *also* to *keep only* the first `X-1` elements, which can be done with [`.Take()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take):

```
steps = steps.Take(fromIndex - 1).ToList();
```

Semantically you can then clarify the meaning of `fromIndex` to something like `keepCount`:

```
steps = steps.Take(keepCount).ToList();
```

(Adjusting for the off-by-one calculation when setting that value, of course.)

Comment: Watch out for critical path scenarios if using this approach. It is highly memory inefficient because an entire new list needs to be created: this will cause unnecessary GC pressure over time.